# numpy dot products of 3 matrixes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, linear-algebra

I'm looking to combine 3 matrixes in a particular way, I'm sure this will be easy for anyone used to using numpy:

```
w = np.array([[-0.46733567,  0.38864732],
                 [-0.42436867, -1.08760098],
                 [-1.01118741,  0.99096466]])   

a = array([[ 0.63127368,  0.00167775,  0.97812284]])

d = [[-0.43252997]] # although d is length 1 in this example, its often >1 in length and code needs to be able to generalize, there will always be the same length of cols and and arrays between a and w, i.e in this example there are 3 arrays in w and 1 of length 3 in a (please excuse my terminology, I am new to linear algebra).
```

I am trying to combine them to find dx so that:

```
dx1 = [-0.46733567,  0.38864732] * 0.63127368 * -0.43252997
dx2 = [-0.42436867, -1.08760098] * 0.00167775 * -0.43252997
dx3 = [-1.01118741,  0.99096466] * 0.97812284 * -0.43252997
```

if d is > length 1, e.g. d= np.array([[-0.43252997],[0.87500009]]) then:

```
dx1_1 = [-0.46733567,  0.38864732] * 0.63127368 * -0.43252997
dx2_1 = [-0.42436867, -1.08760098] * 0.00167775 * -0.43252997
dx3_1 = [-1.01118741,  0.99096466] * 0.97812284 * -0.43252997
dx1_2 = [-0.46733567,  0.38864732] * 0.63127368 * 0.87500009
dx2_2 = [-0.42436867, -1.08760098] * 0.00167775 * 0.87500009
dx3_2 = [-1.01118741,  0.99096466] * 0.97812284 * 0.87500009
```

I tried all of these but with seemingly no success, unless I'm missing something?

```
out = np.dot(d, w) * a 
out = np.dot(d, w) * a.T 
out = np.dot(d, w.T) * a 
out = np.dot(a, w) * d
out = np.dot(a, w.T) * d
```

I get an error in many cases:

```
ValueError: shapes (3,1) and (3,2) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 3 (dim 0)
```

any pointers to help solve this would be much appreciated

Comment: Seems like a basic linear algebra problem. You have a dimension mismatch, so dot product won't work

Comment: Which cases *don't* you get this error, and what error *do* you get?

Comment: your example doesn't look as if you need a dot product. You want to get `len(a)*len(d)` vector of length 2, right?

Comment: to multiply 2 matrix A m x n, and B n x o, they must share the dimension n.

Comment: Curious if any of the solutions posted here work for you?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response - very helpful insight from everyone, especially as I'm new to this area. I'm finding the code a bit harder to follow what its doing with the broadcasting method so have opted for the 2nd answer, though I'm sure I'll come back to looka t broadcasting when I'm a bit more advanced - thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need any dot product, since you dont want to sum anything.

I am repeating your arrays in a third axis (this gets relevant if d is longer than 1).

And then multiply the appropriate axis...:

```
w = np.array([[-0.46733567,  0.38864732],
                 [-0.42436867, -1.08760098],
                 [-1.01118741,  0.99096466]])   

a = np.array([[ 0.63127368,  0.00167775,  0.97812284]])

d = np.array([[-0.43252997]])

(dim1, dim2), dim3 = w.shape, len(d[0])  

wnew = w.reshape(dim1, dim2, 1)
anew = a.reshape(dim1, 1, 1)
dnew = d.reshape(1, 1, dim3)

product = wnew * anew * dnew
i, j = 0, 0
print product[i, :, j]
```

the last statement prints what you called `dx_ij`

Comment: Wait, why do you need repeat here? Doesn't broadcasting deal with it?

Comment: yes, it's probably the same, only I'm not familiar with broadcasting ... and: "explicit is better than implicit" :)

Comment: I'd argue that it's better to use a library as it is designed to be used. The explicit reshapes are reasonable, but the repeats are totally unnecessary, and presumably slower

Comment: ah, I see what you mean, to leave only the `repeat`. Yes, this sounds right. It works the same without them, so I'll edit them away.

Answer (score 2):

Going by the format of the input arrays, specifically that shapes of all input arrays are `2D` and assuming you would like to store the output in a `3D` array, here's an approach using [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
(w.T)[:,:,None]*(a[0,:,None]*d[:,0])
```

Sample run -

```
In [48]: # Input arrays
    ...: w = np.array([[-0.46733567,  0.38864732],
    ...:                  [-0.42436867, -1.08760098],
    ...:                  [-1.01118741,  0.99096466]])   
    ...: 
    ...: a = np.array([[ 0.63127368,  0.00167775,  0.97812284]])
    ...: 
    ...: d= np.array([[-0.43252997],[0.87500009]])
    ...: 
    ...: dx1_1 = np.array([-0.46733567,  0.38864732]) * 0.63127368 * -0.43252997
    ...: dx2_1 = np.array([-0.42436867, -1.08760098]) * 0.00167775 * -0.43252997
    ...: dx3_1 = np.array([-1.01118741,  0.99096466]) * 0.97812284 * -0.43252997
    ...: dx1_2 = np.array([-0.46733567,  0.38864732]) * 0.63127368 * 0.87500009
    ...: dx2_2 = np.array([-0.42436867, -1.08760098]) * 0.00167775 * 0.87500009
    ...: dx3_2 = np.array([-1.01118741,  0.99096466]) * 0.97812284 * 0.87500009
    ...: 
    ...: # Let's store these in a 3D array
    ...: p1 = np.column_stack((dx1_1,dx2_1,dx3_1))
    ...: p2 = np.column_stack((dx1_2,dx2_2,dx3_2))
    ...: out = np.dstack((p1,p2))
    ...:
```

Print outputs from original and proposed broadcasting based approaches for verification -

```
In [49]: out                                 # Output from original approach
Out[49]: 
array([[[  1.27603568e-01,  -2.58139646e-01],
        [  3.07954650e-04,  -6.22986533e-04],
        [  4.27800472e-01,  -8.65432403e-01]],

       [[ -1.06118124e-01,   2.14674993e-01],
        [  7.89247187e-04,  -1.59663239e-03],
        [ -4.19244884e-01,   8.48124609e-01]]])

In [50]: (w.T)[:,:,None]*(a[0,:,None]*d[:,0]) # Output from proposed solution
Out[50]: 
array([[[  1.27603568e-01,  -2.58139646e-01],
        [  3.07954650e-04,  -6.22986533e-04],
        [  4.27800472e-01,  -8.65432403e-01]],

       [[ -1.06118124e-01,   2.14674993e-01],
        [  7.89247187e-04,  -1.59663239e-03],
        [ -4.19244884e-01,   8.48124609e-01]]])
```

---

If the input arrays `a` and `d` are `1D` arrays :

```
a = np.array([ 0.63127368,  0.00167775,  0.97812284])
d = np.array([-0.43252997,0.87500009])
```

, the solution would simplify to -

```
(w.T)[:,:,None]*(a[:,None]*d)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you multiple two matrix they should have a shared dimension.
In your example:

```
>>> out = np.dot(a, w)
>>> print out
[[-1.28479419  1.21280327]]
```

for more info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication
If A is an n × m matrix and B is an m × p matrix,the matrix product AB (denoted without multiplication signs or dots) is defined to be the n × p matrix.

Best Regards,
Yaron